# AFNetworking ElfSundae UIWebView-Patch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, afnetworking

I have updated the AFNetworking Pod to get rid of the UIWebView
 as at
https://github.com/ElfSundae/AFNetworking/issues/1
suggested.

But now I get some depreciated warnings: 
`'GET:parameters:progress:success:failure:' is deprecated.`

At the code:
`[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) { ....`

I have double checked the code with the migration-guide - but I can't see whats wrong..

Thank you

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit [ded6a76](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/ded6a7694619c77261f3ee878343f7966fbe70ac) added `GET:parameters:headers:...` method to support setting headers per HTTP request, and deprecated `GET:parameters:...` method.

My fork is based on the latest commit on the master branch of AFNetworking, includes this commit.

The old `GET` method without `headers` parameter is just deprecated, you can use it safely, or migrate your code to use the new `GET` method passing `headers:nil`. Or you may create a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` to disable the warnings:

```c
@interface MyHTTPSessionManager : AFHTTPSessionManager

// These three methods below have been marked as deprecated in AFNetworking,
// we override them here and remove DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE to silence the
// deprecated-warning.


- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                            parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                               success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                               failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure;

- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                             parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                                success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                                failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure;

- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                             parameters:(nullable id)parameters
              constructingBodyWithBlock:(nullable void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                                success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                                failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure;

@end

@implementation MyHTTPSessionManager

- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                            parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                               success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                               failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure
{

    return [self GET:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:success failure:failure];
}

- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                             parameters:(nullable id)parameters
                                success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                                failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure
{
    return [self POST:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:success failure:failure];
}

- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                             parameters:(nullable id)parameters
              constructingBodyWithBlock:(nullable void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                                success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                                failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure
{
    return [self POST:URLString parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:block progress:nil success:success failure:failure];
}

@end
```

code from [ESAPIClient](https://github.com/ElfSundae/ESAPIClient/blob/master/ESAPIClient/ESAPIClient.h#L90)

Comment: Thank you very much!!